# Error localhost:3000 - Errno::ECONNREFUSED at /courses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, server

I'm trying to preview a page with courses and I get this error:

[image]

`Errno::ECONNREFUSED at /courses`

```
Connection refused -
{:data=>"fq=type%3ACourse&fq=hidden_b%3Afalse&sort=university_sponsor_b+desc%2C+university_partner_b+desc%2C+score+desc%2C+score+desc%2C+name_s+asc&start=0&rows=15&q=%2A%3A%2A", :method=>:post, :params=>{:wt=>:ruby}, :query=>"wt=ruby", :headers=>
{"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, :path=>"select", :uri=>#<URI::HTTP:0x0055dda6f37c60 
URL:http://localhost:8982/solr/development/select?wt=ruby>, :open_timeout=>nil, :read_timeout=>nil, :retry_503=>nil, :retry_after_limit=>nil}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you install Solr? The Sunspot gem requires the 3rd party application Solr. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: I did not, doing it right now

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before, maybe you didn't set the db properly.
Try something like this:

```
rake db:drop rake db:create rake db:migrate # rake db:seed
```